# Vue3 composition API useMutation appolo response

Tags: graphql, vuejs3, vue-apollo

I am building a Vue3  app with the composition API. Installed it correctly. In my template is a button (just for testing purpose):

```html
<button @click="getToken"> get token </button>
```

When I click this button I can see in the chrome developer tools (network tab) that this Graphql mutation is executed and is respponding correctly.

```js
<script setup>
import { useQuery, useMutation } from "@vue/apollo-composable";
import gql from "graphql-tag";
 
const { mutate: getToken} = useMutation(gql`
  mutation login {
    login(
      authProfileUuid: "1234567"
      username: "email@company.com"
      password: "secret"
    ) {
      jwtToken
    }
  }
`,)

</script>
```

My problem is that i just can't figure out how to get access to the JSON data in the response. Its my first time using apollo and can't find it in the docs. Can anyone help me ?

Martijn D.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you should change your code to this:

```
<script setup>
import { useQuery, useMutation } from "@vue/apollo-composable";
import gql from "graphql-tag";

const { mutate: getToken, onDone } = useMutation(gql`
    mutation login {
        login(
            authProfileUuid: "1234567"
            username: "email@company.com"
            password: "secret"
        ) {
            jwtToken
        }
    }
`);

onDone((res) => {
    console.log(res);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).